# Slick carousel - need ellipses in the navigation of synced slider

Tags: css, slick.js

I have this [code here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PLdQRR) that shows what I am working on.
In various cases I might have a large amount of divs to go through so I want to show ellipses of some kind in the bottom navigation.
Let say I have 16 slides. So what I want navigation to show is

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ...16

...3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11...16

My guess ellipses parts "..." and "...16" should be its own separate divs located on the sides of the slider itself. I can't seem to add them properly. Of course ellipses div should only be seen when user is not on the first div. "...16" should be seen until they reach last div.

This is just an example. As long as it fits properly under top slider.
Please help.

HTML

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="slider slider-single">
                <div><h3>1</h3></div>
                <div><h3>2</h3></div>
                <div><h3>3</h3></div>
                <div><h3>4</h3></div>
                <div><h3>5</h3></div>
                <div><h3>6</h3></div>
                <div><h3>7</h3></div>
                <div><h3>8</h3></div>
                <div><h3>9</h3></div>
                <div><h3>10</h3></div>
            <div><h3>11</h3></div>
            <div><h3>12</h3></div>
            <div><h3>13</h3></div>
            <div><h3>14</h3></div>
            <div><h3>15</h3></div>
            <div><h3>16</h3></div>
            </div>
        <div class="ellipses"><span>...</span></div>
            <div class="slider slider-nav">
                <div><h3><span>1</span></h3></div>
                <div><h3><span>2</span></h3></div>
                <div><h3><span>3</span></h3></div>
                <div><h3><span>4</span></h3></div>
                <div><h3><span>5</span></h3></div>
                <div><h3><span>6</span></h3></div>
                <div><h3><span>7</span></h3></div>
                <div><h3><span>8</span></h3></div>
                <div><h3><span>9</span></h3></div>
                <div><h3><span>10</span></h3></div>
                <div><h3><span>11</span></h3></div>
                <div><h3><span>12</span></h3></div>
                <div><h3><span>13</span></h3></div>
                <div><h3><span>14</span></h3></div>
                <div><h3><span>15</span></h3></div>
                <div><h3><span>16</span></h3></div>

            </div>
        <div class="ellipses2"><span>...16</span></div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
    h3, .ellipses, .ellipses2 {
    background: #f0f0f0;
    color: #3498db;
    font-size: 2.25rem;
    margin: .5rem;
    padding: 2%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.slider-single h3 {
    line-height: 10rem;
}

.slider-nav h3::before{
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 75%;
}

.slider-nav h3 span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.ellipses span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.slider-nav .slick-slide { cursor: pointer; }

.slick-slide.is-active h3 {
    color: #c00;
    background-color: #fff
}
```

JS

```
 $('.slider-single').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: true,
    fade: false,
    adaptiveHeight: true,
    infinite: false,
    useTransform: true,
    speed: 400,
    cssEase: 'cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.18, 1)',
 });

 $('.slider-nav')
    .on('init', function(event, slick) {
        $('.slider-nav .slick-slide.slick-current').addClass('is-active');
    })
    .slick({
        slidesToShow: 10,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
     arrows: false,
        dots: false,
     swipe: false,
        focusOnSelect: false,
        infinite: false,
        responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 1024,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 5,
                slidesToScroll: 5,
            }
        }, {
            breakpoint: 640,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 4,
                slidesToScroll: 4,
            }
        }, {
            breakpoint: 420,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 3,
                slidesToScroll: 3,
        }
        }]
    });

 $('.slider-single').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
    $('.slider-nav').slick('slickGoTo', currentSlide);
    var currrentNavSlideElem = '.slider-nav .slick-slide[data-slick-index="' + currentSlide + '"]';
    $('.slider-nav .slick-slide.is-active').removeClass('is-active');
    $(currrentNavSlideElem).addClass('is-active');
 });
```

Comment: still can't get any help here...